# How can I bring back disappeared or hard-blocked wifi on linux?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, bluetooth, wifi-driver

On my HP6370b laptop the wifi connection disappeared. There is no icon for wifi connection, the network setting still shows the previously used wifi connection but it does not connect to it. How can I get the wifi connection back?

Answer (score 3):

You can block RF (radio-frequency) devices of your computer in two different levels:

- soft-block
- hard-block

The difference is that the soft-block is available on all computers and it can be turned on and off by some appropriate commands. The hard-block, on the other hand, requires some more direct change on the computer.

For example, the Wifi or the Bluetooth devices can be disabled

- in you BIOS/UEFI settings
- by a hotkey combination like Ctrl+F12 (see you computer's manual for the exact combination)
- by a physical switch on you hardware

These are all hard-blocks.

There is a really useful command line tool in linux called `rfkill`. It lists and lets you manipulate all the radio-based devices of your computer and works like this:

```
rfkill
$ rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE            SOFT      HARD
 0 bluetooth hci0         unblocked unblocked
 1 wlan      phy0         unblocked unblocked
 2 wlan      hp-wifi      unblocked unblocked
 3 bluetooth hp-bluetooth unblocked unblocked
```

This list shows that the computer has four wireless devices, 0 and 3 are bluetooth and 1 and 2 are wifi. At this stage they are all unblocked, that is, all of them can be used.

When I had the wifi-issue I mentioned in the title of this question, the values in the `HARD` column were all `blocked`.

### Unblocking *hard* blocks

In order to unblock *hard* blocks, you need to change back your UEFI/BIOS settings, apply the appropriate hotkey or use the physical switch. On my HP HP6370b laptop the physical switch is a touch-button right above the F6 and F7 function keys of the built-in keyboard. It looks like a wifi-symbol but it is responsible for Bluetooth as well. Its color can be either blue or yellow. Blue means it is turned ON, yellow means OFF. You just have to touch that shiny symbol to toggle the state. When it goes blue, the `rfkill` command will display `unblocked` for each devices in their `HARD` column. Done.

### Unblocking *soft* blocks

If the device is not hard-blocked, it still can be soft-blocked. In order to unblock it, you can use a command like this:

```
sudo rfkill unblock 2
```

where `2` is the ID of the device in the output of `rfkill`.

As opposed to the *listing*, for *toggling* a setting you need root access. That's why I used `sudo`. When you unblocked the soft-blocks of all the devices then `rfkill` displays `unblocked` in both the `HARD` and the `SOFT` columns in each line. Done.

It shouldn't be necessary to reboot after unblocking the RF devices but you may need to restart some services. Maybe it is easier just to reboot if things don't work yet.

In my case, the problem was that I did not know what that wifi symbol does above the function keys. We normally use this laptop as a desktop replacement and the lid is always closed. Recently we had to move the laptop and probably we hard-blocked the RF devices by accident.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, for some strange reason, rfkill showed my wifi devices as hardblocked and softblock would be off whiles my airplane mode was off (as in normally accepting network connections).

And it would switch to the opposite (hardblock-no, softblock-yes) when in airplane mode.

So what I did was turn my airplane mode on, and then unblock the hardblock via `sudo rfkill unblock [ID number]` Example `sudo rfkill unblock 0`.

My issue was resolved after that.

Now using the keyboard shortcuts to enable and disable wifi / airplane mode works as it should normally.

Cheers.